# Building OpenSSL under Borland C++ Builder, Win 8.1

Tags: c++, openssl, c++builder, borland-c++

I'm following the instructions from INSTALL.W32 (various OpenSSL versions), in general it's:

```
 * Configure for building with Borland Builder:
   > perl Configure BC-32

 * Create the appropriate makefile
   > ms\do_nasm

 * Build
   > make -f ms\bcb.mak
```

Now, I do get two kind of errors when trying to build:

For OpenSSL < 1.0.0

```
nasmw -f obj -d__omf__ -ocrypto\md5\asm\m5_win32.obj .\crypto\md5\asm\m5_win32.asm
'nasmw' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Otherwise

```
Warning W8017 C:\CBuilder5\Include\sys/stat.h 34: Redefinition of 'S_IFMT' is not identical
Warning W8017 C:\CBuilder5\Include\sys/stat.h 35: Redefinition of 'S_IFDIR' is not identical
Error E2227 .\crypto\rand\randfile.c 226: Extra parameter in call to _open in function RAND_write_file
Warning W8053 .\crypto\rand\randfile.c 262: '_chmod(const signed char *,int,...)' is obsolete in function RAND_write_file
*** 1 errors in Compile ***
```

Yes, I feel bad for using Borland C++ Builder 5 but I can't do anything about it, and yes, I consider the Shining Light option if everything else fails.

Comment: Have you searched the web for tutorials on using Borland C++ Builder 5 to build OpenSSL?  There seem to be explicit instructions.

Comment: Of course, that was the first thing I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for the newest version (1.0.2d) was to:

1. remove the extra parameter from randfile (which, as comment stated, was unnecessary),
2. edit ms\bcb.mak, search for `-DMD5_ASM -DSHA1_ASM -DRMD160_ASM` 
   and change to `-DMD5_NO_ASM -DSHA1_NO_ASM -DRMD160_NO_ASM` . (there was an unresolved external error with SHA, MD5 and RMD160, they basically couldn't be compiled in asm).

There were some other steps included as well, but they're just specific to my environment.

Answer (score 0):

I do not use OpenSSL but from your text some hints:

1. [NASM](http://www.nasm.us)

   - is not default assembler for Borland compilers
   - you need to download and install it first
   - (it is for free and one of the best compilers I used in the past)
2. you are missing some `#define` before including OpenSSL or including in wrong order

   - that is why you have the first warnings and most likely also the error
   - some libs need to add configuration `#defines` (added by some specific IDE's)
   - to specify what compiler,platform,endianess...  is used
   - before any includes
   - usually if you include in wrong order then the defines are defined for some instances of a lib file but not for all
   - so try to reorder the includes
   - sometimes helps to include before the lib some other thing like conio,stdio,windows,...
   - to determine which define is missing or wrong open the `stat.h`
   - and look for `#ifdef` `#ifndef` statements around `S_IFMT`

Answer (score 0):

In the Windows XP SP3 environment, I added "-DOPENSSL_NO_POSIX_IO" to the CFLAG in the bcb.mak file, which resolved this error message.